Emitting a Kafka Message from HTTP message in Spring cloud function web and spring cloud function stream
While I am trying to produce a Kafka message from HTTP message in spring using both spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka (Kafka Streaming) and spring-cloud-function-web (HTTP calls) in a reactive way as follows:
Event class is used for receiving an HTTP message and emitting a Kafka message
import org.springframework.messaging.Message
import org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux
import reactor.core.publisher.Sinks

class Event : Consumer<Flux<Message<String>>> {

    protected val logger  = loggerFor(javaClass)
    protected val unicastProcessor = Sinks.many().unicast().onBackpressureBuffer<Message<String>>()

    @Transactional
    override fun accept(t: Flux<Message<String>>) {
        t.map { msg ->
            val txt = msg.payload.let { MessageBuilder.withPayload(it).build() }

            logger.info("Received HTTP Message: $txt")

            unicastProcessor.emitNext(msg, Sinks.EmitFailureHandler.FAIL_FAST)
        }
        .subscribe()
    }
}

And here is my configuration:
  cloud:
    function:
      scan:
        packages: com.example.blabla.functions
    stream:
      bindings:
        produce-out-0:
          destination: stats-topic
          binder: kafka
        consume-in-0:
          destination: stats-topic
          binder: kafka
          group: stats
      default-binder: kafka
      kafka:
        binder:
          auto-create-topics: true
          auto-create-partitions: true
          brokers: "kafka:9092"
          consumer-properties:
            key.deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
            value.deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
          producer-properties:
            key.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
            value.serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
          transaction:
            transactionIdPrefix: transactionPrefixTest

And my configuration bean for the producer:
    @Bean
    fun produce(): Supplier<Flux<Message<String>>> = Supplier {
        unicastProcessor.asFlux()
    }

And for some reason, the message does not get emitted to Kafka configured topic after receiving it in the HTTP call, putting in mind that the message is received successfully in the HTTP layer but not pushed to Kafka topic afterwards.
Your help is much appreciated. May I know why it is not delivering the message to Kafka?
Last log of the received message from the HTTP layer:

2024-09-17T16:02:39.477Z  INFO 6010 --- [jvmtask] [or-http-epoll-2] com.example.blabla.functions.Event    : Received HTTP Message: GenericMessage [payload=text to log 3, headers={id=6b339ecf-d62f-fe28-f7b9-10520587a66e, timestamp=1726588959474}]


Any chances to have a simple project from you to reproduce on our side an play with?

sure thing:
https://github.com/manonworldrepository/spring-cloud-function-web-and-cloud-function-stream-kotlin

Thank you, but your sample is too complicated. Any chances to make it smaller (without any unnecessary deps (Avro?), and no Docker). We simply could use an @EmbeddedKafka. But still no any HELP.md you mention in the root README. And totally not clear how to run. I also don't see consume function definition. There is also no spring-cloud-stream-reactive reactive for a while. Consider to remove it altogether: might cause some conflicts in classpath.
